If a new line opens, what's the optimal strategy for $i$th person?
If there are $n$ people in a queue, and a new line opens, each person can choose either to stay in the original line or to switch to the new line. Each person should decide at the same time. If a person switches to the new line, they will retain their relative position.
For example, if the original queue is $q_1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]$, and persons $2$ and $4$ decide to switch to the new line, the resulting queues will be $q_1: [1, 3, 5]$ and $q_2: [2, 4]$.
What's the optimal strategy for $i$th person in the line?
I believe there is no deterministic strategy for the $i$th person, except for when $i = 1$ or $i = n$. If all the other people decide to switch to the new line, the optimal strategy for me would be to stay in the original line. Conversely, if everyone else stays in the original line, the optimal strategy would be to switch to the new line.
Therefore, for the $i$th person, the strategy should be a mixed strategy, where $p_i$ represents the probability of switching to the new line. Additionally, $p_1 = 0$ and $p_n = 1$.

What determines how many people move when a new queue opens?

@Grey Everyone can decide to change or not. I think the $i$th position will affect the probability, if $i$ is close to 1, then p is close to 0. If $i$ is close to n, then p is close to 1.

If we assume everyone is rational player, then there would be no utility for the first person to move. However, the second person would be first on the new line so he/she must move. Third person knows that the second would move so he/she stays. This way the optimal is for everyone in even position to move while everyone is odd positions stay.

I proposed that, for each pair of people ($2k-1, 2k$), they will choose different queues, and different pairs can have different strategies independently. Apparently there's no benefit nor cost for person $1$ to switch queue.

@quantinho you're assuming that people will by default remain in the original queue and not move to the new queue. But what if each person decides randomly in such a case? Then the first person chooses randomly, so second person chooses arbitrarily, and so on so every person will remain in the original queue and switch with equal probability.

@ShreyaMundhada "if each person decides randomly", then what is the point of the question?

@quantinho In some questions such assumptions can lead to non-trivial questions, as sometimes an element of randomness is present, but yes, in this case it makes more sense to say that unless there is some utility in shifting the person remains on his/her line.

I will add a minor assumption before I answer this question: moving to the new line costs some utility, but less than that of getting a better spot in line.
With this assumption, we have that person one will stay in the original line because it gives him the same place without having to pay the cost of switching lines. From here, person 2 will want to switch lines because it gives her a better spot. This goes on with person 3 getting a second place in line regardless of switching or not so he will opt to stay in the original line so that he doesn't pay the cost of switching. This continues with every odd person staying in the original line and every even person switching.
Now I will also answer the game where switching lines has zero cost. Then player 1 is indifferent between lines, because of this he can stay in his line with probability $p_1$. There are 3 cases $p_1 < .5$, $p_1 = .5$, and $p_1 > .5$.
If $p_1< .5$ then player 2 has a better expected payout if he always stays in the original line because it will be occupied less often the the new line. From here, player 3 will want to switch, player 4 will want to stay and so on.
If $p_1 > .5$ then the opposite will happen, player 2 will switch , player 3 will stay.
If $p_1=.5$ then, then player 2 will be in the position player 1 was in above so we can think of the same choices for $p_2$, the probability player 2 stays, effecting how player 3 chooses.
